# Rails 3 ActiveRecord conditional includes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I know this can be done:

```
Article.where("published_at <= ?", Time.now).includes(:comments)
```

But what if I'd like to only get comments posted in the past month?

Does the .includes operator allow conditions?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
Article.includes(:comments).where("articles.published_at <= ? and comments.created_at >= ?", Time.now, Time.now - 1.month)
```

EDIT:

```
Article.joins(:comments).where("articles.published_at <= ? and comments.created_at >= ?", Time.now, Time.now - 1.month)
```

Comment: Wow, didn't know I could do that. Thank you so much.

Comment: Actually, this query only returns articles that *have* a comment posted in the past month. I need to have *all* the articles returned, along with each article's comments posted in the past month (if there's any).

Comment: `joins` does an inner join. Same problem. `includes` does a left outer join, which is what we want, but the desired filter is applied on the where clause and not in the join.

Comment: @Derek were you able to find a solution?

Comment: NOTE: here, **comments** is used as **relation name in the join**, and as **table name in the where**. If you defined `has_many comments, class_name: "Post"`, you would have written `Article.joins(:comments).where("... posts.created_at >= ?", Time.now - 1.month)`

Comment: @bfcoder this question might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25099668/pgundefinedtable-error-missing-from-clause-entry-for-table-when-using-joins

Answer (score 4):

In Rails4, it should be: 
`Article.includes(:comments).where("articles.published_at <= ? and comments.created_at >= ?", Time.now, Time.now - 1.month).references(:comments)`

[Source](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/includes)

Comment: Note that `includes` works with association names while `references` needs the actual table name.