# PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table when using joins and where

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, psql

I have two models, `Courier` and `Order`.

I have the following query below:

```
active_couriers = Courier.
  available_courier_status.
  where(:service_region_id => @service_region.id).
  includes(:orders)
```

This query works, however, it pulls in all orders. I want to limit the orders to only orders for the day. So I added the following query `where("orders.created_at >= ?", Time.zone.now.beginning_of_day)`.

```
active_couriers = Courier.
  available_courier_status.
  where(:service_region_id => @service_region.id).
  includes(:current_orders).
  includes(:orders).
  where("orders.created_at >= ?", Time.zone.now.beginning_of_day)
```

This give me the error:

```
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "orders"
```

What am I doing incorrectly here?

Answer (score 93, accepted):

Hmm it looks like you're trying to include `current_orders` and include `order`. Are these the same tables with different conditions? This might be confuse active record. Also, I'm pretty sure it's wise to include the `references` method when referencing a joined table. Perhaps, try something like this:

```
active_couriers = Courier.includes(:orders)
  .available_courier_status
  .where(:service_region_id => @service_region.id)
  .where("orders.created_at >= ?", Time.zone.now.beginning_of_day)
  .references(:orders)
```

Comment: Thank you. I guess you need to add `references`

Comment: This was a life-saver. I had to use different names for the `includes` and the `references` clauses due to renaming of associations, but hell, it only took me 3 minutes after I found this fantastic answer. Thanks!

Comment: Docs for references method: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-references

Comment: adding references fix the issue for me. Thanks a lot

Comment: You can use here `Time.zone.today` instead of `Time.zone.now.beginning_of_day`

Answer (score 14):

You can also use `eager_load` to provide the same exact behavior as `includes` + `references` does. It performs the same Left Outer Join on the table passed as an argument, but in a much cleaner manner.

Docs here: http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.7/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/eager_load

Per this example:

```
active_couriers = Courier.eager_load(:orders)
  .available_courier_status
  .where(:service_region_id => @service_region.id)
  .where("orders.created_at >= ?", Time.zone.now.beginning_of_day)
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to provide `.includes(:service_region)` before filtering with `where`.