# PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table when using SELECT DISTINCT ON

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

I am trying to get a list of uniq `patients` who have submitted an `esas_assessment`, sorted by the time the `esas_assessment` was `created_at`; for a `clinician` that `has_many` `patients` `:through` a table called `care_group_assignments`.

What I have here was working but stopped working when I made it so that `clinicians` `has_many :esas_assessments, :through => :patients` instead of having 
`esas_assessment` having a `clinician_id` field and being tied directly to a clinician.  I needed to make this choice so that multiple clinicians could be associated with an `esas_assessment`.

This is what I had before changing how `esas_assessments` were associated with `clinicians`.  This was based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29686732/protocolviolation-error-bind-message-supplies-0-parameters-but-prepared-state).

```
<% @esas_assessments.order("patient_id, created_at DESC").select('ON (patient_id) *').uniq.limit(99).each_with_index do |esas_assessment, index| %>
```

This now gives me:

> PG::AmbiguousColumn: ERROR:  ORDER BY "patient_id" is ambiguous

I don't actually understand why these are ambiguous since neither `patients` or `clinicians` have the fields `patient_id` or `created_at`.

To try to deal with this I used [this answer](https://railsforum.com/topic/59730-trying-to-solve-pgambiguouscolumn-error-column-reference-user-id/) and added `esas_assessment.` before the ambiguous fields.

```
<% @esas_assessments.order("esas_assessment.patient_id, esas_assessment.created_at DESC").select('ON (esas_assessment.patient_id) *').uniq.limit(99).each_with_index do |esas_assessment, index| %>
```

This gives me error:

> PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "esas_assessment"

```
: SELECT  DISTINCT ON (esas_assessment.patient_id) * FROM "esas_assessments"
INNER JOIN "patients" ON "esas_assessments"."patient_id" = "patients"."id"
INNER JOIN "care_group_assignments"
ON "patients"."id" = "care_group_assignments"."patient_id"
WHERE "care_group_assignments"."clinician_id" = $1
ORDER BY esas_assessment.patient_id, esas_assessment.created_at DESC LIMIT 99
```

I have also tried using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25099668/pgundefinedtable-error-missing-from-clause-entry-for-table-when-using-joins) since it seems like a similar problem but can't figure it out.

Any help would be great.

Rails 4.1.8, ruby 2.2.1p85, PostgreSQL

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you are just missing an `s` on your table name:

```
<% @esas_assessments.order("esas_assessments.patient_id, 
  esas_assessments.created_at DESC")
  .select('ON (esas_assessments.patient_id) *')
  .uniq.limit(99).each_with_index do |esas_assessment, index| %>
```

The table name is `esas_assessments`, not `esas_assessment`.

Comment: a beautifully simple answer - thanks.  do you know why it was ambiguous without adding `esas_assessments.` before the column names?

Comment: Well, i assume `@esas_assessments` is already populated by some query. Maybe this query brings a `patient_id` from another table, so when you try to use `order` in a previous `ActiveRecordRelation` it complains that it doesn't know which `patient_id` you are talking about. 

But this is just a guess anyway. =]