# Rails 5 custom query using where.not in has and belongs to many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a `product` model with a `has_and_belongs_to_many` association with `tags`.  I am trying to create a custom query to exclude certain products with a particular tag.  With the code below I get the error `PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column products.product_id does not exist...` If I remove `.where.not(products_tags: 'Mouldings')` from the `@stones` query, products will list based on the `@products` model.

**product.rb**

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  include PgSearch
  pg_search_scope :search_for,
                  against: %i(name body),
                  associated_against: { variations: :name, categories: :name, tags: :name },
                  using: {
                      tsearch: {
                          any_word: true
                      }
                  }

  has_and_belongs_to_many :categories
  has_and_belongs_to_many :tags
  ...
end
```

**tag.rb**

```
class Tag < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :products
end
```

**products_controller.rb**

```
  ...
  def index
        if params[:query]
          @products = Product.search_for(params[:query])
          @stones = @products.where.not(products_tags: 'Mouldings')
        else
          ...
        end
  end
  ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [include or joins](http://tomdallimore.com/blog/includes-vs-joins-in-rails-when-and-where/).

For example, if include the tag table, and then query:

```
      @products = Product.search_for(params[:query]).includes(:tag)
      @stones = @products.where('tag.name != ?', 'Mouldings')
```

Comment: I tried both and I get this error `PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column products.tag does not exist` - being noobish, I think I should of mentioned that the association between products and tags is done through a join table `products_tags`

Comment: When you call a join table,  such as products_tags - it is looking for an `id` unless you specificy another attribute. The issue here is that youre passing in a string, instead of an id. What is the name of the attribute on the tags table, that holds the value `Mouldings`. That is what you need to query for.

Comment: the attribute on the tags table is `name` - I have been trying everything and running into brick walls...

Comment: I updated the answer - you need to call the attribute you're trying to query. In this case, `tags.name` not just `tags`

Comment: I am getting close.  Currently getting error `PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "tags"` then I found this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25099668/pgundefinedtable-error-missing-from-clause-entry-for-table-when-using-joins so I updated my code to `@stones = Product.includes(:tags).where('tags.name = ?', 'Mouldings').references(:tags)` which displays only products with `Mouldings` tag but errors out when I use `where.not`

Comment: Great! Just do `.where('tags.name != ?', 'Mouldings')`

Answer (score 0):

I could not find a solution to my problem (which is similar). Here is what I did:

My Models

```
class Allergy < ApplicationRecord
   has_and_belongs_to_many :items
end

class Item < ApplicationRecord
   has_and_belongs_to_many :allergies
end
```

Given a list of allergies, I want to find the items that do not have those allergies. Example:

```
allergies = ['dairy', 'eggs']
```

So I did was create two scopes, it makes the code more understandable (and useful):

```
class Item < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :allergies

  scope :with_allergy, ->(n) { includes(:allergies).where(allergies: {name: n}) }

  scope :free_of, ->(a) { self.all.where.not(id: self.with_allergy(a)) }
end

# I can pass one allergy
Item.free_of('dairy')

# I can pass multiple allergies
Item.free_of(['dairy', 'eggs'])
```

You can change 'name' to any attribute you want (including id).

I had to create the two scopes because the following:

```
Item.includes(:allergies).where.not(allergies: {name: n})
```

**Did not return items that are not associated with any allergies**. Instead, it returns records that have at least one association.

**Possible solution for Rails 6.1>**

Rails 6.1 added a `.missing` method that **returns all records that do not have any association**.

```
Item.missing(:allergies) # returns items that do not have any associated allergies.
```

The latter can be combined with where clauses.

Source: https://boringrails.com/tips/activerecord-where-missing-associations